# Having problems in IE8 when attempting to get data from target event

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8, jquery-events, custom-data-attribute

I have code such as this..

```
// Get some data
var id = event.target.id;
var flag_status = event.target.dataset.change;
var winner_id = event.target.dataset.winner;
var item_id = event.target.dataset.item;
```

"Normal" browsers like `Firefox` and `Chrome` get the values with no problems and everything works great; however nothing is happening with `IE8` so I'm assuming it can't get the data.

The `event` parameter is passed to this function via this code:

```
$('.shipping_status').click(function(event) {

    event.preventDefault();
    
    // Update Shipping Status
    updateShippingStatus(event);
    
});
```

..and then in turn gets it when one of these example elements is clicked:

```html
<a title="Item Being Processed" class="shipping_status processing" data-item="102383" data-winner="172" data-change="0" id="processing_102383" href="#"></a>                            
<a title="Item Posted" class="shipping_status posted active" data-item="102383" data-winner="172" data-change="1" id="posted_102383" href="#"></a>
<a title="Problem With Item" class="shipping_status problem" data-item="102383" data-winner="172" data-change="3" id="problem_102383" href="#"></a>
<a title="Item Delayed" class="shipping_status delayed last" data-item="102383" data-winner="172" data-change="2" id="delayed_102383" href="#"></a>
```

Is there a way I can get this to work with IE8? ...additionally, I don't have IE9+ to test with - does anyone know if it works in IE9+?

I have also tagged this with jQuery if there is an alternative way to get this data with jQuery that will work with IE8 as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like IE just started supporting the `dataset` attribute in IE11: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.dataset

Try just using `getAttribute()`:

```
var flag_status = event.target.getAttribute('data-change');
var winner_id = event.target.getAttribute('data-winner');
var item_id = event.target.getAttribute('data-item');
```

If you are using jQuery, it makes this easy using the `data()` method:

```
var $target = $(event.target);
var flag_status = $target.data('change');
var winner_id = $target.data('winner');
var item_id = $target.data('item');
```

Only use `data()` if the attributes on the HTML element won't change.  From [jquery documentation](https://api.jquery.com/data/):

> The data- attributes are pulled in the first time the data property is
>   accessed and then are no longer accessed or mutated (all data values
>   are then stored internally in jQuery).

If you need to re-read HTML attributes that change, just use the `attr()` method:

```
var $target = $(event.target);
var flag_status = $target.attr('data-change');
var winner_id = $target.attr('data-winner');
var item_id = $target.attr('data-item');
```

Comment: Just tried the jQuery solution, whilst it works; if the data changes without a page reload it fails to return the new value - it still returns the previous value.

Comment: The jquery `data()` method must not be doing 2-way binding with the HTML attribute.  That is, I bet it just reads the attribute the first time, and doesn't revisit the DOM.  Maybe just use the `attr` method: `$target.attr('data-change')`.  I'll update the answer.

Comment: @SeanAdkinson -- Correct.  The `data()` method will read the `data-*` attributes the first time it is invoked, but there is NOT two-way binding since the `data` method can take more complicated objects and not just primitives.

Comment: Thanks @JeremyJStarcher, I found the explanation in the jquery documentation and updated the answer.  That makes sense about the more complicated objects.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use event.preventDefault() in IE8, but you should use event.returnValue instead.

A solution would be: `(event.preventDefault) ? event.preventDefault() : event.returnValue = false;`

Answer (score 0):

use

```
var item_id =  $(this).attr("data-item")
```

etc. inside click event